# D+ and D- voltages when using USB PD V2

Tags: usb-c, usb-pd

I'm trying to design a power circuit for a project I'm working on, using USB type-C PD V2 at 20V. I also want to use the D+ and D- pins for programming the microcontroller. I'm worried that the D+ and D- voltages are tied to VBUS which will kill the microcontroller if I allow them to short to 20 volts. Is the D pair tied to bus voltage, and if so, how should I go about protecting the microcontroller? I don't want to do PD and data transfer at the same time, but as it stands, there is nothing stopping the Data line from going high to 20V.

[image]

Comment: Ground is shared, not VBUS. Add a schematic to your question.

Comment: USB data is 3.3V logic, with pull ups on the upstream facing device

Comment: Why do you believe that D+ and D- are " tied to VBUS"?